# If $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \bigl(f(k)\bigr)^{2} =\ln(2)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose we have

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \bigl(f(k)\bigr)^{2} =\ln(2)$$ Then is $\displaystyle f(k) = \frac{1}{k+1} -\frac{1}{k+2} +\frac{1}{k+3} -\cdots = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{k+i}$ ?

Comment: We could have $f(1)=\sqrt{\ln2},\forall k\ne1,f(k)=0$...

Comment: What you are really asking about can be boiled down to this: If $A+B = 2$ do we neccesarily have $A=B=1$? In this example you have can tune $A$ to what you want and then $B=2-A$ gives a solution. In you question its even worse: you have infinite amount of freedom to tune the different $f(k)$'s to obtain the desired sum.

Answer (score 0):

Also $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {6\ln(2)}{\pi^2 (n+1)^2}=\ln (2)$ because $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{ (n+1)^2}=\frac {\pi^2}{6}$

Comment: Isn't that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{n^2}=\frac {\pi^2}6$?

Comment: @abiessu ,yes, but i started it for $0$ so the series will match to the OP's:)

Comment: @Winther, haha. didn't see that . thnx